# Input dinâmico retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando criar um campo de busca dinâmico. O problema é que quando eu digito alguma alguma coisa, não consigo pegar o valor do campo o JavaScript. Só me retorna `undefined`.

Meu código:

```js
$('.search').focus( function () {
  var timer = 0;
  var input = $('.search');
  input.keyup(function (e) {
      var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
      if (code > 45 || code === 32 || code === 8 || code === 13) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
          timer = setTimeout(function () {
              input = input.val()
              alert('neste momento coloca a chamada AJAX '.input)
          }, 200);
      }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
<label for=""></label>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Buscar anime..">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

O que está errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está na concatenação.

Você colocou `.input`.

O certo é `+input`:

```
alert('neste momento coloca a chamada AJAX ' + input)
```

Comment: Vdd, testei e funcionou